# Accessing and Using entities of other features in Clean Architecture

Tags: flutter, architecture, entity, clean-architecture

I've created feature packages for every part of my application and my project structure looks like this :

```
app
    core
    features
        main
            domain
            data
            ui
        feature1
            domain
                entities
                    entity1
                    entity2
                …
            data
            ui
        feature2
            domain
                entities
                    entity1
                    entity2
                …
            data
            ui
```

My question is that can I use **entities** of **feature1** and **feature2** in my **main** feature? And if it is not correct way, Is there any better solution for this?
Thank you all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The better question is, why would you seperate the domain layer over several features?
In clean architecture the domain model is suggested to be one package at it self which has no dependencies to other packages.

Therefore you I would put the domain model into an own package and let the different features access it by their use cases.

[Clean architecture by Uncle Bob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZgzk.png)

Comment: Should I separate whole domain layer(including repository contracts and usecases)? Or only the entities?

Comment: Only the Entities, UseCases would be another own layer often refered as application layer :)

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what [MartinPeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14651284/martinpeek) says, **NOWHERE** in the Clean Architecture book is it written that *"the domain model is suggested to be one package"*. The [popular clean architecture diagram](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/images/2012-08-13-the-clean-architecture/CleanArchitecture.jpg) is in no way a guide on how you should implement your application's directory structure. In fact, Uncle Bob has clearly stated that a 'Screaming' architecture will have its application use cases visible from the top. And in its last chapter called "The Missing Chapter" contributed by Simon Brown, he evaluates different ways of packaging and starts off with how packaging by layer violates Clean architecture rules.

When you implement packaging by layer your source directory will have different subdirectories such as `domain`/`entities`, `use-cases`, `data-access-gateway`/`repositories`, `web-api`, `presenters`, `views`, etc. which screams **Clean Architecture**, but not the intent of your system i.e. **Healthcare Management Application**, or **Shopping Cart Service**. And when you try to make a single change in a single feature, you'll have to consequently make changes across 4 different packages.

If you want to implement Clean architecture truthfully, then instead of dividing your packages according to horizontal layers, you should divide it vertically across the layers. You should have the application layer (domain entities and use cases) in the root directory itself. Each package should map to a domain in your business logic, this way all the use cases and entities that change for the same reason are packaged together, and all the use cases and entities that change for a different reason are segregated. That way, you'll end up with a directory structure like so: `database`, `api`, `employee`, `wages`, `taxes`. And without even giving you any hint you have a general idea of what this application might be about.

You can have data access layer, API, and UI related modules in their own separate packages inside the root directory as well, and have the use cases access them, OR you can even have them encapsulated inside the "vertical slice" itself, as Uncle Bob states:

> If you decouple the elements of the system that change for
> different reasons, then you can continue to add new use cases without interfering with
> old ones. If you also group the UI and database in support of those use cases, so that
> each use case uses a different aspect of the UI and database, then adding new use cases
> will be unlikely to affect older ones.

But of course, that has its own pros and cons.

For further reading, I found this blog very helpful when I first started off: [Explaining Clean Architecture](https://www.oncehub.com/blog/explaining-clean-architecture)

Coming to your question,

> can I use entities of feature1 and feature2 in my main feature?

Entities are allowed to talk to each other, in fact its part of any business logic, but as we go higher up the layers from abstraction towards concretion, you should keep things more segregated. Again, when you make a change, you shouldn't need to change use cases that have nothing to do with that change. So I would suggest you to create a separate use case that accesses both entities, or create a separate entity that is an aggregate of feature1 and feature2 entities, and implement a new feature to access it. And then you can have your main feature use this newly created use case.